# Need non-recaptcha captcha check for website - javascript disabled on client browsers - fight spam orders

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha, server-variables

I'm trying to figure out how to beat the robot scripts at their own game without using Re-Captcha.

What I would like to do in PHP is determine if the previous URL is from the same website and page cart.php, (i.e. https://www.thissite.com/cart.php) since I think they are submitting the form through robot script into the address page.

Is my theory right? Will this actually work?

If the previous URL is not matching the website address, dump them to google.com. Can this redirection be done without using headers?

Comment: You're coming to us with a solution without explaining a problem. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: "Will this actually work?" no. your talking about using HTTP referer , it can be faked by the bots. it can be blank by legitimate humans

Comment: Ok, the problem is I tried using Re-Captcha and what happened is some users did not see the re-captcha dialog box so the captcha check failed upon submitting. Previously, we came under a robot script attack where it kept submitting the form numerous times (+800) creating a huge number of bogus orders. I instituted the captcha to try eliminating the problem but then ran into a problem with legitimate users unable to place orders. What I'm looking for I guess is a way to ensure that the form is actually being submitted by a real life person and not a robot script.

Comment: The root problem: robot scripts generated 800+ bogus orders attempting to do sql injection - these attempts failed using parameterized queries.

Comment: To avert robot scripts, implemented Re-captcha, some users could not see the dialog box for them to check. So I'm looking for a way to determine real from bogus form submits.

Comment: The best way (in my opinion) is to have a non-required form element that is positioned absolutely, and far outside of the viewport. A regular user would not attempt to fill in this field, while a bot would. Simply check that this field is blank in `$_POST`.

Comment: Ok, that sounds simple enough. At least it would avert 99% of the bot scripts out there. Not to say a more sophisticated attacker would be able to bypass it. Do you have any ready examples that show how that is done? I'd almost considered using a simple check where I display an image that says to submit, leave this checkbox unchecked. If the checkbox is checked, dump their sorry butt to google.com. Would that work as well?

Comment: Can you post your answer @ObsidianAge so I can mark it? Your recommendation worked well. Many thanks! Is there anywhere or way I can do some type of automated testing as a robot script submitter the same way the bad actors do? I mean I could wire up a C# routine to do the test but if there is a way without reinventing the wheel, that would be great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to verify if a form is submitted by a robot or not is to have a non-required form element that is positioned absolutely, and far outside of the viewport. A regular user would not attempt to fill in this field, while a bot would.

```css
#robot {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9000px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required><br /><br />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required><br /><br />
  <input id="robot" type="text" name="robot">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the form above, a true user would only see the first and last name fields. They'd have no reason to suspect there was an invisible `robot` field. Conversely, a robot would read the DOM, see a named `<input>`, and attempt to fill it out.

You can then check for the presence of this field in your form submission:

```
if (!isset($_POST['robot'])) {
  // Legitimate submission
}
else {
  // You've caught a bot!
}
```

Hope this helps! :)